# Ansible register and .changed not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook that installs a package, and needs to run a command if the package is installed. I used `register <variable>` and `<variable>.changed` to do this, however, this doesn't seem to work in Ansible 2.0 unless I'm doing it wrong. Here's my code.

```
- name: install syncthing (arch)
  pacman: name=syncthing state=latest
  when: ansible_distribution in ['Archlinux', 'Manjaro Linux']
  register: syncthing

- name: enable syncthing
  command: systemctl enable syncthing@jay.service
  when: syncthing.changed
```

What happens is the first block installs the syncthing package, and gives me the following output:

changed: [myhost]

Then the next block should execute since the previous step registered a change, but unfortunately, it doesn't:

skipping: [10.10.99.193]

I'm hoping that there's an easy solution to this, I seem to be doing this correctly from what I've read of the documentation, as well as the following post: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Ansible_-_Only-do-something-if-another-action-changed.html

Comment: Can you print `syncthing` between the plays and post the results? `- debug: var=syncthing`

Comment: That's a good idea. But one thing I just tried is the same role against a Debian host. It works perfectly fine. Arch Linux is the only one that has an issue with it, apparently.

Comment: I tried your debug command, and got the following:
"syncthing": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Again, this is only in Arch Linux. It looks like Ansible and Arch Linux has a bug. I've decided to stop using Ansible with Arch Linux from now on, it's too much of a hassle to manage a rolling release with Ansible.

Comment: What happens if you drop the when criteria?

Comment: Without the criteria, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: install syncthing (arch)
  pacman: name=syncthing state=latest
  when: ansible_distribution in ['Archlinux', 'Manjaro Linux']
  register: syncthing

- name: enable syncthing
  command: systemctl enable syncthing@jay.service
  when: ansible_distribution in ['Archlinux', 'Manjaro Linux'] and syncthing is defined and syncthing.changed
```

Comment: This answer is just code, While it may well answer the question, it offers not explanation for itself.